# how to send values form the window form appliction to an asp.net server and get the values form database from there?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, webforms

I want user to get the user name and password in the windows form the send it to a web form for the verification, where after verification from the database the entries(which are courses joint by the user) are sent back to the window form, I searched alot but could not get any suitable method, I am new ti c# and asp.net..
I found a way here I am placing my code please tell me is there any better way to do my job.but instead of getting the desired values i get the whole html code so i used to enclose my desired value in html tags on server side which and on client side  I am getting the values by using the regular expressions
Here is code for windows from which sends after getting values from the text boxes

```
 try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://localhost:50612/Inclusive_LMS/speech/login.aspx/?stdId=" +tb_stdId.Text + "&pass=" + tb_pass.Text);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            string content = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

            Match valid = Regex.Match(content, @"(?<=(<span[^>]*>))([^<]*)(?=(</span>))");

            if (valid.Success)
            {
                this.Hide();
                Student_dashboard ins = new Student_dashboard();
                ins.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("invalid user Id or password");

            }


           // textBox2.Text = "" + content + "";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("check your internet connection, failed to connect the server.");

        }
```

Here is the code for "http://localhost:50612/Inclusive_LMS/speech/login.aspx" page,on designer side I had only one  lable on html page

```
    SqlDataReader r;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Student where Std_Id='" +Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["stdId"]) + "' and Password='" +Request.QueryString["pass"]+ "'", con);
   try
   {
    con.Open();
        r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (r.Read())
            Label1.Text = "success";
        else
            Label1.Text = "fail";
        con.Close();
     }
      catch
      {
          Label1.Text = "error";
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the best approach would be to access the database directly from the windows application (If it is possible) for any task.

If it is not possible for you to access database directly, you can create a web service in your `webform` project and consume it in the `winforms` application. This is easy to implement and works well.

The third approach is to use `WebAPI` in ASP.NET framework for doing this task.

You need to choose what fits best in your scenario. Best of luck!

**Update:**
Visit [ASP.NET Official Website](http://www.asp.net/web-api) for lots of resources.

Comment: I don't have any knowledge of web ApIs and web services would you please provided me some easily understandable reference  links or sample code for working with web service and web APIs..

Comment: Watch these series of videos about web services I am sure It will help you understand.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xzJm0lPIoJY